A collation that ignores cedillas for comparison?
Cedillas are mutations applied to letters in some languages, like portuguese, french, turkish and romanian. Some words: "coração", "açúcar", "linhaça" (letters 'Ç', 'Ş', ...).
How to choose a collation that ignores cedillas for comparison? They are not accents.
This blog post (in portuguese) teaches that:

SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI: considers cedillas
Latin1_General_CI_AI: ignores cedillas

What is the difference? It's not clear in the name of the collation.

SQL_ collations are older and therefore generally less accurate.
From SQL Server Collation Name (Transact-SQL):

SQL Server supports Windows collations. SQL Server also supports a limited number (<80) of collations called SQL Server collations which were developed before SQL Server supported Windows collations. SQL Server collations are still supported for backward compatibility, but should not be used for new development work.

You can expect more modern and correct behaviour from non-SQL_ collations, as they always reflect the more capable operating system comparisons based on the Unicode rule sets. The old collations were much more limited, using only a single code page and simple semantics that consider only one character at a time on non-Unicode strings.
You can see the details using sys.fn_helpcollations:
SELECT 
    C.[description]
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() AS C
WHERE
    C.[name] = N'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';

This returns:
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, 
   kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data, 

SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data

Notice the compatibility rules used for non-Unicode data.
For more information about Windows collations, see Windows Collation Name (Transact-SQL). For more information about collations, see Collation and Unicode Support.
